# Angular 7 Pipe não funciona mesmo exportado e declarado no module principal

Tags: angular, pipe

Olá, eu tenho um Pipe que transforma um numero em string dizendo o mês referente.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'nomeMesPipe',
    })
    
    export class NomeMesPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: any): any {
        if (value) {
          switch (
            value // Converte o numero em nome do mês
          ) {
            case 0:
              value = 'Janeiro';
              break;
            case 1:
              value = 'Fevereiro';
              break;
            case 2:
              value = 'Março';
              break;
            case 3:
              value = 'Abril';
              break;
            case 4:
              value = 'Maio';
              break;
            case 5:
              value = 'Junho';
              break;
            case 6:
              value = 'Julho';
              break;
            case 7:
              value = 'Agosto';
              break;
            case 8:
              value = 'Setembro';
              break;
            case 9:
              value = 'Outubro';
              break;
            case 10:
              value = 'Novembro';
              break;
            case 11:
              value = 'Dezembro';
              break;
          }
        }
        return '';
      }
    }
```

Esse pipe é exportado e declarado em um modulo chamado **Shared.module** .

```
declarations: [
     ...
     NomeMesPipe,
     ...
 ],
exports: [
      ...
      NomeMesPipe,
     ...
  ],
```

que por sua vez é exportado e importando no meu **app.module.ts**

```
exports: [SharedModule],
imports: [
     ...
     SharedModule
     ...
 ],
```

e usado no meu componente como  **{{ data.mes |nomeMesPipe }}**.
Esse componente possui um modulo mas eu não importo o pipe aqui pois já esta no app.module.

Contudo ele apresenta erro.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
> 'nomeMesPipe' could not be found

eu já tentei deixar apenas no modulo shared, já tentei deixar no modulo do componente, e também já tentei colocar nos dois módulos, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: teoricamente tem que estar no export do seu shared module

Comment: eu corrigi o texto da pergunta, na verdade, ele já esta no export do shared module e não no import.

Comment: tenta importar o SharedModule no modulo que vc delcara esse componente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu retirei do modulo shared e do app module, e foi apenas necessários incluir na declarations do modulo do meu componente

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [... , NomeMesPipe],
  exports: [...],
....
```

E funcionou.